# Como usar Result em função definida pelo usuáro?

Tags: rust, recuperação-de-erros

Muitas funções em rust aplicam o enumerável `Result` em sua implementação. Esse enumerável facilita o  gerenciamento de erro, já que você pode usar `unwrap` ou `expect` para ajudar a identificar o erro em um código.

Um exemplo é quando se lê um arquivo, que pode não estar no diretório, usando `std::io::File`:

```rust
use std::io::File;

fn main () {
    let text = File("hello.txt").expect("Unable to read file");
    println!("{}",text);
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para implementar isso nas minhas próprias funções.

Eu tentei assim:

```rust
use std::io::Error;

fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");
    let len = calculate_length(&s1).expect("Please, entry a valid string");
    println!("The length of '{}' is {}.", s1, len);
}

fn calculate_length(s: &String) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let solution = s.len();
    if solution > 0 {
        return solution;
    } else {
        return Error;
    }
}
```

Não funcionou.

Como faço para usar o `Result` nas minhas funções?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html

Comment: Nesse caso como a função não retorna muita informação relevante no caso de erro, talvez utilizar `Option` também seja uma boa opção, utilizando a variante `None` como representante do (único) erro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como dito na própria pergunta, o `Result` é uma enumeração. Em muito resumo, o problema é só retornar os valores que deveriam estar dentro do `Result`. Quando se instancia um `enum`, deve-se explicitar qual das variantes deve ser utilizada.

---

Em Rust, as enumerações permitem que um único tipo possa assumir significados diferentes, o que pode ser muito útil em algumas situações.

Enumerações em Rust podem envolver valores. Por exemplo:

```
enum Color {
    Rgb(u8, u8, u8),
    Hex(String),
}
```

Nesse caso, a enumeração `Color` aceita valores que representam cores nos formatos RGB e hexadecimal.

Para criarmos um valor do tipo `Color`, precisamos fornecer os valores na instanciação do *enum*. Assim:

```
let rgb_c = Color::Rgb(255, 0, 0);
let hex_c = Color::Hex("#3399cc");
```

Note que é importante informar ao compilador *qual variante* do `enum` deve ser usada (no caso acima, fizemos isso com `Color::Rgb` e `Color::Hex`). Caso contrário, o compilador não seria capaz de saber a qual variante o programador se refere, já que a única informação típica sobre a instância da enumeração é o tipo do `enum` (no caso acima, `Color`).

No caso do `Result`, a enumeração prevê dois estados possíveis: `Ok`, para casos análogos a sucesso; e `Err`, para casos análogos a erro.

---

Portanto, voltando ao exemplo da pergunta, não é factível retornar da função *apenas* o valor que deveria estar *contido* na instância da enumeração `Result`.

Você deve, explicitamente, informar a variante. Assim:

```
fn calculate_length(s: &String) -> Result<usize, &'static str> {
    let solution = s.len();
    if solution > 0 {
        return Ok(solution);
    } else {
        return Err("Invalid length.");
    }
}
```

Como o padrão de retornar `Result` é muito comum, o Rust inclui, no [*prelude*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html), além do próprio `Result`, os nomes `Result::Ok` e `Result::Err`. Assim, ao invés de escrever o "nome completo" da variante, você pode utilizar os nomes diretamente, sem a necessidade do prefixo `Result::`. O mesmo acontece para `Option`, tal que `Some` e `None` também são disponíveis à nível global.

---

Não deixe de ler:

- [Enums and Pattern Matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-00-enums.html)
- [Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)